# qam demapper why are soft-outputs used?

Tags: ofdm, demodulation

I'm starting to learn about OFDM QAM demapping, and a lot of documentation points to using "soft-output" algorithms that calculate Log-Likelihood Ratios (LLRs).

Why is this method advantageous?

My naive approach would be to just place a grid over the IQ map, and find which grid-square my symbol lands in.

Comment: Soft-output algorithms for QAM are really not where you should start learning. Learn hard-decision QAM decision, and then learn about soft-output BPSK; then it *might* make mathematical sense to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My naive approach would be to just place a grid over the IQ map, and find which grid-square my symbol lands in.

And that's (more or less) exactly how it's done: it's called a *hard decision*, and your  grid is what we'd call the *decision boundaries*. It's a result of applying the *Maximum Likelihood* criterion to the decision process.

Of course, in that decision, a sample that hits a constellation point (nearly) exactly is not distinguishable from a sample that was somewhere "in the middle" between two constellation points (and hence close to one of the decision boundaries).

You can't tell "absolutely certain" from "I'm about 51% sure" decisions that way! So, this hard deciding throws away valuable information.

If you find a way to encode the decision information and the certainty of that decsion into numbers, then you get a *soft-output decider". The most common way of finding a single number that describes that is through *likelihood ratios*, i.e. divide how likely one symbol is by the likelihood of a different symbol. Because ratios are unelegant to deal with, apply a logarithm to it, and get a LLR.

Now, you want bits, not something like "I'm almost certain this was a 0 or 1", but don't forget:

In modern systems, you use channel coding. If you have an algorithm that doesn't only consider single symbols, but *sequences* of symbols, then you can use these soft-outputs to infer the likeliest sequence that was sent more reliably.

As said in my comment to your question, you *really* shouldn't start learning about QAM mapping by reading about soft-output decision on QAM. Start with soft-output BPSK, and then learn about the hard- and soft-output *Viterbi* sequence estimator. (For Viterbi, you'll need working knowledge of simple convolutional channel codes, but that should be comparatively simple when considering you're doing LLRs on QAM...)